# current activity taking screenshot and save image into sdcard in android

Tags: android, screenshot, sd-card

Hi In my application I am making an application in android in which I have to take screenshot of current activity and save it into sdcard.

For that i used one menu button named as download if i click the download i want to save the current activity into sdcard.

Now My problem is it's saving into sdcard but screenshot coming half.I want to download the whole screen and save it into sdcard.how to download the full activity.

Can anyone please help me how to solve this problem.

**notify_image**

```
public class notify_image extends Activity {



        ImageView imageView;

        Activity av=notify_image.this;
        Bitmap b;
        String strFileName;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.notify_image);


            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_imageview);
            Intent in = getIntent();

            String title = in.getStringExtra("TAG_TITLE");
            String url = in.getStringExtra("TAG_URL");
            String name = in.getStringExtra("TAG_NAME");
            String place = in.getStringExtra("TAG_PLACE");
            String date = in.getStringExtra("TAG_DATE");
            final String URL =url;
            TextView stitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            TextView sname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            TextView splace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_place);
            TextView sdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_date);  

            // displaying selected product name
            stitle.setText(title);
            sname.setText(name);
            splace.setText(place);
            sdate.setText(date);






            // Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask
            GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
            // Execute the task
            task.execute(new String[] { URL });
        }


        //creating button
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.downloads, menu);
            return true;
        }

        //button on click function
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
            switch (item.getItemId()) {    
                case R.id.downloads:
                    /*Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                       saveBitmap(bitmap);
                    */
                    //captureScreen(v); 
                    try{
                        Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenShot(av); // av is instance of hello
                        savePic(bitmap, strFileName);
                        }
                    catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }

         return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }



        }
       private static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity) {
            View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            view.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
            Rect frame = new Rect();
            activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
            int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
            int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getHeight();
            // Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, 25, 320, 455);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height
             - statusBarHeight);
            view.destroyDrawingCache();
            return b;
                }
        /*public void takeScreen() {
            Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtils.loadBitmapFromView(this, view); //get Bitmap from the view
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "screen_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg";
            File imageFile = new File(mPath);
            OutputStream fout = null;
            try {
                fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
                fout.flush();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                fout.close();
            }
        }*/
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
       private static void savePic(Bitmap bitmap, String strFileName) {
            //File strFileName1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshottt.png");
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("mnt/sdcard/print.png");
            if (null != fos) {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            System.out.println("b is:"+bitmap);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

            public static void shoot(Activity a,String b) {
            //savePic(takeScreenShot(a), "sdcard/xx.png");
            savePic(takeScreenShot(a), b);
            }
      /*public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
               View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
               rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
               return rootView.getDrawingCache();
            }*/
        /*public Bitmap captureScreen(View v)
        {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
        if(v!=null)
        {
        int width = v.getWidth();
        int height = v.getHeight();

        Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        v.draw(new Canvas(screenshot));
        }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        Log.d("captureScreen", "Failed");
        }

        return bitmap;
        }
        */
       /* public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                    view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            view.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        }*/
       /* public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
            File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }*/

        //image url convert to bitmap

        private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                Bitmap map = null;
                for (String url : urls) {
                    map = downloadImage(url);
                }
                return map;
            }

            // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            }

            // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
            private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                InputStream stream = null;
                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

                try {
                    stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                            decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;
            }

            // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
            private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                    throws IOException {
                InputStream stream = null;
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                try {
                    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpConnection.connect();

                    if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return stream;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks In Advance.

**new updated code**

```
public class notify_image extends Activity {



    ImageView imageView;

    Activity av=notify_image.this;
    Bitmap b;
    String strFileName;
    Button download;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notify_image);


        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_imageview);
        download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        download();

        Intent in = getIntent();

        String title = in.getStringExtra("TAG_TITLE");
        String url = in.getStringExtra("TAG_URL");
        String name = in.getStringExtra("TAG_NAME");
        String place = in.getStringExtra("TAG_PLACE");
        String date = in.getStringExtra("TAG_DATE");
        final String URL =url;
        TextView stitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        TextView sname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        TextView splace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_place);
        TextView sdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_date);  

        // displaying selected product name
        stitle.setText(title);
        sname.setText(name);
        splace.setText(place);
        sdate.setText(date);






        // Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask
        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
        // Execute the task
        task.execute(new String[] { URL });
    }


    //creating button
   /* public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.downloads, menu);
        return true;
    }
*/
    //button on click function
   /* public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
        switch (item.getItemId()) {    
            case R.id.downloads:
                Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                   saveBitmap(bitmap);

                //captureScreen(v); 
                try{
                    Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenShot(av); // av is instance of hello
                    savePic(bitmap, strFileName);
                    }
                catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);
        }

     return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    }*/

   private void download() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), KnowYourLeader.class);
            startActivity(nextScreen);*/
       try{
           Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenShot(av); // av is instance of hello
           savePic(bitmap, strFileName);
           }
       catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}

        }





private static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity) {
        View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
        Rect frame = new Rect();
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
        int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
        int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
        .getHeight();
        // Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, 25, 320, 455);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height
         - statusBarHeight);
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
        return b;
            }
    /*public void takeScreen() {
        Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtils.loadBitmapFromView(this, view); //get Bitmap from the view
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "screen_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg";
        File imageFile = new File(mPath);
        OutputStream fout = null;
        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
            fout.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            fout.close();
        }
    }*/
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   private static void savePic(Bitmap bitmap, String strFileName) {
        //File strFileName1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshottt.png");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("mnt/sdcard/print.png");
        if (null != fos) {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        System.out.println("b is:"+bitmap);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        public static void shoot(Activity a,String b) {
        //savePic(takeScreenShot(a), "sdcard/xx.png");
        savePic(takeScreenShot(a), b);
        }
  /*public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
           View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
           rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
           return rootView.getDrawingCache();
        }*/
    /*public Bitmap captureScreen(View v)
    {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
    if(v!=null)
    {
    int width = v.getWidth();
    int height = v.getHeight();

    Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    v.draw(new Canvas(screenshot));
    }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    Log.d("captureScreen", "Failed");
    }

    return bitmap;
    }
    */
   /* public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }*/
   /* public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }*/

    //image url convert to bitmap

    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Bitmap map = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                map = downloadImage(url);
            }
            return map;
        }

        // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

        // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
        private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream stream = null;
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

            try {
                stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                        decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
        private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException {
            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its beacause of your menu bar. just put your code in to some button click in to screen it will take full screen image.

Comment: it's showing blank image

Comment: means blank but full scrren image or half screen image?

Comment: how i know it's full screen or half screen it's not displaying any image it showing white image

Comment: hi can you please help me

Comment: hi patel can you please edit my code tell me where i did mistake

Comment: can you post your code after update to click on button?

Comment: hi patel then also it's showing half image

Comment: just now i posted my updated code

Comment: when you call download button??

Comment: after displaying listview

Comment: call  download(); method in onPostExecute of async task : GetXMLTask

Comment: i have scroll option after scroll data it's not diplaying

Comment: @patel help me plaese

Comment: in which way i have already give u hint

Comment: after adding button it's not storing into sdcard

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that allowed my screen shot to be stored on sd card and used later for whatever your needs are, you can achieve it with following code:

```
// image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" +  ACCUWX.IMAGE_APPEND;   

// create bitmap screen capture
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = view.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

OutputStream fout = null;
imageFile = new File(mPath);

try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, when you need to access use something like this:
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath));

Comment: What are you trying to suggest by above code? (You should include brief about solution you are trying to suggest!)

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code to capture the whole screen and save as bitmap.:

```
View v = view.getRootView();
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myPath = new File(extr, "print.jpg");
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage( getContentResolver(), b, 
                                         "Screen", "screen");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: hi image not saving into sdcard

Comment: @jyothi Make sure you have provided WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest file.

Comment: @jyothi Its for capturing image.